# Same dependency in 2 modules

Tags: android

if you have 2 modules that has dependency on support v14
do you put the same dependency in both modules or you put it in one? I mean does it make the apk include the code twice and hit the 65 k limit

Thanks

Comment: you can put the dependency in one module and make the other module depend on this module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the dependency in every module that needs it. Doing so makes the modules more independent. You can reuse a module in another project without having to worry about the dependencies.
It will be included in the APK only once.

Comment: Thank you. The last sentence is what I was looking for

Comment: I was worry about apk size. But your last word has overcome my hesitation.